# Интерн врача-терапевта

Tags: грамотная-речь, словосочетания

Фотографии врачей-интернов в разделе "Специалисты клиники" на сайте одной из клиник имеют подписи вида ***"интерн врача-терапевта"***, ***"интерн врача-анестезиолога"*** и т. д.
Мне такая формулировка показалась несколько спорной, поэтому я решил поинтересоваться у находящихся в тот момент рядом со мной людей, что они думают по данному поводу.

Оказалось, что не только нет единства в том, допустимы ли в принципе такие формулировки, но и сама возможная роль родительного падежа слова ***"врач"*** в данном контексте трактуется разными людьми по-разному.
Одни воспринимают родительный падеж как указание на то, что ***"интерн"*** в данном случае — это некая промежуточная форма развития врача (например, ***"личинка комара"***, ***"птенец ястреба-тетеревятника"***, ***"интерн врача-терапевта"***, т. е. когда-нибудь личинка станет комаром, птенец — ястребом-тетеревятником, а интерн — врачом-терапевтом), в то время как другие полагают, что родительный падеж здесь означает отношение принадлежности (например, ***"холоп барина"***, ***"арап Петра Великого"***, ***"интерн врача-терапевта"***, т. е. у какого-то барина есть холоп, у Петра Великого был арап, а у врача-терапевта есть в этой клинике интерн).

Если честно, лично мне оба эти варианта кажутся не совсем корректными. На мой взгляд, слово "интерн" уместно только в сочетании с существительными в том же падеже, например: ***"врач-интерн"***, ***"терапевт-интерн"*** и т. д.

В связи с этим вопрос: существуют ли в русском языке какие-либо правила использования слова ***"интерн"*** в приведенных выше сочетаниях?

Comment: Но ведь интерн - *врач, стажирующийся у другого врача*.

Comment: @oleedd, формально - возможно, да. Это как раз второй вариант значения этого словосочетания, описанный в вопросе. Но как-то уж очень коряво это звучит. И судя по результату поиска Гугла по запросу ***"интерн врача-терапевта"*** (с сохранением кавычек), этот вариант можно увидеть только на сайте этой клиники и у нас в этом обсуждении. Это и наводит на подозрения, что что-то с этим вариантом не то.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, это что-то разговорное в значении  "стажёр врача-терапевта".

Чаще видим такое написание: врач-терапевт (интерн), видимо, это литературная норма, встречается и "врач-интерн-терапевт", но мне почему-то это тоже не нравится, хотя приемлемо: должность врач-интерн (равнозначно врач-стажёр), специализация терапевт.

Comment: *Я думаю, это что-то разговорное в значении "стажёр врача-терапевта".*  - не понял. Вы считаете "стажер врача" - литературной нормой?

Comment: Тоже разговорное, но привычное выражение, стажёры есть у всех специалистов, почему бы и у  врачей не быть?

Comment: Объяснять значение одного разговорного через другое, еще более разговорное? Но это даже меклочи по сравнению с тем, что "стажер у кого-то". *Помнишь, стажер у нас был из Штатов, тупой такой?* - вот единственное вхождение на весь нацкорпус.

Answer (score 0):

Интернатура - форма стажировки молодых врачей при клиниках и больницах.
Интерн - лицо, проходящее такую стажировку. Других значений в общеупотребительном лексиконе нет, форма "интерн врача" поэтому невозможна. "Врач врача" получается. Может быть, профжаргон. Наподобие "адьютанта его превосходительства".

Comment: Чего так, если диплом выдают только после интернатуры? Кто бы её проходил, если это было бы необязательно.

Comment: Я вас уже один раз попросил не флудить? Не говорите загадками.

Answer (score 0):

Я только сейчас - благодаря предлагаемой правке - вчитался в текст, предваряющий собственно вопрос. Пожалуй что, без ответа на подразумеваемые в этой части вопросы весь ответ нельзя признать полным.

Итак комментарий по поводу "роли родительного падежа".

> Одни воспринимают родительный падеж как указание на то, что "интерн" в
>   данном случае - это некая промежуточная форма развития врача

"Интерн" действительно некая "предварительная форма" врача, но предложенная трактовка сочетания "интерн врача" совершенно невозможна. Можно привести сравнения с аспирантом, кандидатом и доктором наук. ну никто ж в здравом уме не назовет аспиранта "аспирантом кандидата" (если не имеется в виду его научный руководитель), а кандидата в свою очередь - кандидатом доктора. 
Аналогия с личинкой здесь явно не проходит.

> другие полагают, что родительный падеж здесь означает отношение
>   принадлежности (например, "холоп барина", "арап Петра Великого",
>   "интерн врача-терапевта", т.е. у какого-то барина есть холоп, у Петра
>   Великого был арап, а у врача-терапевта есть в этой клинике интерн).

Вот такое как раз возможно. У интернов есть (насколько знаю) руководитель интернатуры, поэтому некоторая принадлежность присутствует. Правда для употребления подобной конструкции нужен специальный контекст, совсем не тот, что на двери с фамилией.

> На мой взгляд, слово "интерн" уместно только в сочетании с
>   существительными в том же падеже, например: "врач-интерн",
>   "терапевт-интерн" и т.д

Отчасти согласен. Но "врач-интерн" в таком раскладе - перебор. "Интерн" обычно противопоставляется полноценному врачу, поэтому написание через дефис вряд ли возможно. А вот "терапевт-интерн" - это уже ближе к истине. Хотя тоже надо разобраться со вкладываемым смыслом.

И конкретно на вопрос.
Как уже говорилось, "интерн" по грамматическому, а отчасти и по смысловому значению эквивалентно "стажер".Это и диктует правила употребления.

Стажер может занимать должность, скажем, капитана. Тогда это капитан-стажер (во флоте, правда, у него обязательно есть наставник, то есть стажер-капитан даже по должности не совсем капитан). Нечто подобное, полагаю законно (с точки зрения грамматики) применимо и к врачу-интерну.

Но по званию интерн врачом не является. Это оксюморон наподобие армейского "генерал-ефрейтор". Отсюда и надо исходить при употреблении. 
Терапевт-интерн - это интерн, частично подменяющий терапевта или помогающий ему. Но никак не статусное обозначение медицинского звания в иерархии таких званий (от нянечки и санитара - до врача-профессора).

И да вот еще что. Не стоит сказанное обобщать на случай ординатора. Интерн и ординатор - это совсем не одно и то же по смыслу. Хотя и то и другое - последний этап в обретении полноценного звания врача.

.

Answer (score -2):

Интерн (врач-интерн) — выпускник медицинского института, проходящий интернатуру (последипломную годичную практику). **Только по завершении** послевузовской профессиональной подготовки (интернатуры) интерну присваивается квалификация в соответствии с выбранной специальностью, например: № 040122 — «терапия», квалификация — «врач-терапевт».

Интернатура является составной частью обязательного полного медицинского образования. Окончившим интернатуру присваивается сертификат врача-специалиста и диплом об окончании интернатуры.

Тогда получается, что "интерн" - **промежуточный этап** перед получением квалификации.

В русском языке нет стилистических правил отдельно по каждому слову. Для этого нужно было бы выпустить 100 томов. И то даже так все "правильные" случаи ими не охватить. Но есть тенденция - если так делают все, то это верно - чего не сказать о данном примере. Тогда и в словари вносятся изменения. Но на запрос "интерн-терапевт" - 47 700 результатов. То есть такая форма является предпочтительной. То есть "врач" заменяется на "интерн", так как полная квалификация врача ещё не получена.

1 сентября 2016 года прием в образовательные и научные организации на обучение по программам послевузовского медицинского и фармацевтического образования в интернатуре прекратился. Таким образом, интернатура в РФ перестала существовать. Её альтернативами стали ординатура и профессиональная переподготовка.